# Running JDK8 for aspectj

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, aspectj

I am trying to run aspectj-maven plugin with JDK8. But it is giving errors like
"The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Any help on how to resolve, or if the aspectj-maven-plugin supports JDK8. I am using 1.6 version of aspectj--maven-plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to achieve the same and I drove crazy trying to figure out this, fortunately I could solve it and here I give you what I did:

To use `aspectj-maven-plugin` with Java 8 you need version aspectj-maven-plugin 1.7 (Note that aspectj-maven-plugin 1.6 works for Java 7).

So, the maven plugin configuration needs to be:

```
        <!-- AspectJ configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

By the way, the aspectJ jars needed are:

```
    <!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And the most important thing I've struggled was that you **need** to install the aspectj-maven-plugin 1.7 jar manually into your pom.xml since this jar aren't on maven repo yet.

You can get it from Haus Jira (look at the Attachment section):

```
https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASPECTJ-131
```

Btw, once you download it an copy it to your repo you need to create your **own** `aspectj-maven-plugin-1.7-SNAPSHOT.pom` file within the corresponding directory. You can copy it from version 1.6 BUT **ensure** you modify the following content:

```
 <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
    <aspectjVersion>1.8.1</aspectjVersion>
    <mavenVersion>2.2.1</mavenVersion>
    <changesPluginVersion>2.9</changesPluginVersion>
 </properties>
```

That's all here you go, hope to help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 1.7-SNAPSHOT for that. I have this snippent in POM and everything works:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to downgrade JDK level to 1.7. JDK 1.7 works well with aspectj-maven-plugin of versions 1.4 - 1.6.

Here is a screenshot showing how to change JDK level in IntelliJ IDEA project:

[image]

Set Project SDK to 1.7. See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html) for more details.